# How to add, update or remove nested objects with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, multidimensional-array, nested-object

I have a possible infinite category tree and I would like to add, update or remove categories at any level with setState in react. I know this is possible with recursion but I don't have enough experience to manage this problem on my own. Here is how the data could possible look like:

```
const categories = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "category1",
    subCategories: [
      {
        id: "sub1",
        name: "subcategory1",
        subCategories: [
          { id: "subsub1", name: "subsubcategory1", subCategories: [] },
          { id: "subsub2", name: "subsubcategory2", subCategories: [] }
        ]
      },
      { id: "sub2", name: "subcategory2", subCategories: [] }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "category2",
    subCategories: []
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your top level categories object is an object and not an array, the add and remove function could be the following (same pattern for update)

```
function add (tree, newCategory, parentId) {
    if(tree.id === parentId) 
      return {
        ...tree,
        subCategories: tree.subCategories.concat(newCategory)
      }
    return {
        ...tree, 
        subCategories: tree.subCategories.map(c => add(c, newCategory, parentId))
    }
}



function remove (tree, idToRemove) {
        if(tree.subCategories.map(c => c.id).includes(idToRemove)) 
          return {
            ...tree,
            subCategories: tree.subCategories.filter(c => c.id !== idToRemove)
          }
        return {
            ...tree, 
            subCategories: tree.subCategories.map(c => remove(c, idToRemove))
        }
    }
```

Comment: this one gives this error if it can't find the id:  subCategories: tree.subCategories.map(c => add(c, newCategory, parentId))

Comment: Yes indeed I kept only the main code. The question was essentially about the recursion principle, nicoxify will be able to adapt these functions with as many input parameter checks as needed.

Comment: thank you I implemented all the needed functionality in my project and learnd a lot about recursion

Answer (score 0):

this is how the recursive function would look like.
the arguments:

> id: id to look for

> cats: the categories array to loop

> nestSubCategory: (boolean) if we want to add the subcategory object in the subCategories array or not

> subCategory: the category object we want to insert

```
const addCategories = (id, cats, nestSubCategory, subCategory)=> {
  const cat = cats.find(item=> item.id === id)
  
  const arrSubs = cats.filter(item => item.subCategories?.length)
  .map(item => item.subCategories)
 
  if(cat){
    if(nestSubCategory){
       cat.subCategories.push(subCategory)
       return
    }else{
       cats.push(subCategory)
       return
    }
  }
  
  else{
    return addCategories(id, arrSubs[0], nestSubCategory, subCategory)
  }
    
}
  

addCategories("blabla1", categories, true,  { id: "blabla2", name: "blablacategory1", subCategories: [] })
  //console.log(categories)
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(categories)
  )
```

remember to update the object in the state replacing the entire categories array once the function is executed.
be careful with recursion

you can do in a similar way to remove items, i leave to you the pleasure to experiment

Answer (score 0):

### Prologue

To update a nested property in an immutable way, you need to copy or perform immutable operations on all its parents.

Setting a property on a nested object:

```js
return {
  ...parent,
  person: {
    ...parent.person,
    name: 'New Name'
  }
}
```

Arrays: You may pre-clone the array, or use a combination of `.slice()`, `.map()`, `.filter()` and the concatenation operator (`...`); Warning: .splice mutates the array.

(this can be a long topic, so I just gave a veryfast overview)

### immer

As this can quickly get very ugly on objects with deep nesting, using the `immer` lib quite becomes a must at some point. Immer "creates new immutable state from mutations".

```
const newState = immer(oldState, draft => {
  draft[1].subcategories[3].subcategories[1].name = 'Category'
})
```

In the extreme case, you can combine immer with lodash to create mutations in arbitrary places:

```
import set from 'lodash/set'
const newState = immer(oldState, draft => {
  set(draft, [0, 'subcategories', 5, 'subcategories', 3], { id: 5, name:'Cat' })
})
```

["You might not need lodash" website](https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash) has the recursive implementation for lodash/set. But, seriously, just use lodash.

PLUSES:

- If you are using redux-toolkit, immer already is auto-applied on reducers, and is exposed as `createNextState` (check docs with care).
- Deeply nested state can be an interesting use case for `normalizr` (long talk).